The struggle to configure Npgsql with PostgreSql cluster read-write and read-only node
We use Npgsql  with .Net8 for web API. Recently we started to have access to a Stackres cluster. With a primary node and several read only nodes.
I'm struggling to find the right way of setup the connection string.
If I understand well the Npgsql Load Distribution documentation the connection string must look like this :
"Host=db-read-write-server, db-read-only-server;Username=test;Password=test;Target Session Attributes=prefer-standby".
But, I don't know if it's the right way to do it.
Another question. Can we mix the Load Distribution configuration with Pooling. By example
"Host=db-read-write-server, db-read-only-server;Username=test;Password=test;Target Session Attributes=prefer-standby;Pooling=true;Maximum Pool Size=4"

Yes, you can use multi-host/load distribution with pooling. What exactly are you struggling with on the connection string?

One of our api try to write on the read-only db, and I don't know why?

Please read the Npgsql docs carefully - the Target Session Attributes parameter is what controls which kind of connection your code needs. prefer-standby means the code is OK with a standby, i.e. it won't be doing writes. For code that needs to write, ensure you get the primary by setting Target Session Attributes=primary.

Thank you @ShayRojansky for your response. I need one more clarification. If I set Target Session Attributes=primary, is Npgsql able to use both a read/write and a read/only connection?

Yes, primaries support both reading and writing.

Did you end up figuring it out? I landed on this question because I'm getting exceptions from Npgsql when I include the Target Session Attributes parameter on the connection string. Doesn't seem well documented.

Hi @Roly, I haven't yet had the time to solve this problem once and for all. So I'm always open to new ideas.
